# Laravel - using a postgre bytea blob field

Tags: php, postgresql-9.1, laravel

I am using PostgreSQL on a Laravel installation.  A table has a bytea type field which is being used to store binary data (base64_encoded file contents).

When I use Eloquent to retrieve the table I get a resource type variable being returned in this field.

How can I rather retrieve this as a string?

```
$raw = Media::where('id','=',$id)->first();
$raw->file_data = base64_decode($raw->file_data);   // doesn't work
```

Comment: try https://github.com/jBernavaPrah/eloquent-binary-cast

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the author of this question did not post the details to the answer, I will post my findings here.

As the returned field is a handle to a stream you can use the [stream_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) function to read the value into a string, you can then use pg_unescape_bytea to get the actual value of the bytea data.  Finally use the htmlspecialchars function if you wish to display the bytea data in HTML.

Example code:

```
$my_bytea = stream_get_contents($resource);
$my_string = pg_unescape_bytea($my_bytea);
$html_data = htmlspecialchars($my_string);
```

Comment: If you're using postgresql`>9` and haven't [`SET bytea_output = 'escape'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/datatype-binary.html) then the invoking to [`pg_unescape_bytea()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php#100436) should be removed to prevent unintended unescape.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to use stream_get_contents on the stream.  duh.