# How do I get the exact text of a postgresql bytea field with Laravel PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, bytea

I have a PostgreSQL bytea field. Using this query in pgAdmin, i get this result:

Query:

```
SELECT bytea_column::text FROM users where email = 'xxxx@gmail.com';
```

Result (text):

```
\014\321\031\353\354\005\263\....
```

If I try to get the value using this Laravel (or direct query from PHP) I get a different result:

```
$result = DB::table('users')
->select(DB::raw('bytea_column::text as result'))
->where('email', '=', 'xxxx@gmail.com')
->value('result');
```

Result:

```
\x01ea86c105cd00eab4606c...
```

Any ideas on how to get the text value that I get with the query on pgAdmin?

Thanks!

Comment: how Are you rendering the output of your query? or is that your result in php artisan tinker?

Comment: Is a simple echo $result, i tried with the complete query using DB::Select, but I get the same result (var_dump).

Comment: this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329323/laravel-using-a-postgre-bytea-blob-field) may be useful

Comment: that post didn't give the exact text I was looking for, but it solve my problem, thanks!