# How can I serve blobs from Postgres as files in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have the following simple file table in my database:

```php
Schema::create('image', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(DB::raw('gen_random_uuid()'));
    $table->binary('image');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In my controller I have the following:

```php
public function getImage(Image $img): Response 
{
    return response($img->image, 200, [
        "Content-Type" => "image/jpeg"
    ]);
}
```

And in my routes I have:

```php
Route::get('/images/{image}', [ImageController::class, 'getImage']);
```

The response has the correct `Content-Type` but the body is completely empty. How can I serve my blobs from Postgres as files over HTTP in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing binary columns on a Postgres database in Laravel the accessor returns a [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) instead of raw data that can be sent to the browser in a response. In order to get that data, you can use [`stream_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php) on the resource. However, as noted in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329323/laravel-using-a-postgre-bytea-blob-field) and [laravel/framework#10847](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10847) there may also be addition encoding / decoding that you need to do.

The easiest solution would be to use [jbernavaprah/eloquent-binary-cast](https://packagist.org/packages/jbernavaprah/eloquent-binary-cast) to handle this for you in your models by doing the following:

1. Add the package to your project by running `composer require jbernavaprah/eloquent-binary-cast`
2. Add `'image' => \JBernavaPrah\EloquentBinaryCast\BinaryCast::class,` to your model's [`$casts` property](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)